# How do I make a substring so that it ends when the next time the same word occurs(in C#)?

Tags: c#, string, substring

For example -

```
string text = "This is some text about a dog. The word dog \nappears in this text a number of times. This is the end";
```

Here, I want to create a Substring that prints till only when the word/string `dog`  appears for the second time which is in this line `The word dog \nappears in this text a number of times`.

I know the solution to this problem which is this -

```
string text = "This is some text about a dog. The word dog appears in this text a number of times. This is the end";
            
string newText = text.Substring(0, 43);
Console.WriteLine(newText);
```

But what if we don't know the index/position of the same word(which is 'dog') that appears for the second time in the line. What would be the code for that?

**Expected Output -**

```
This is some text about a dog. The word dog

Process Finished.
```

Here, when the word dog appears for the scond time, the string ends...

[NOTE: You may ask for clarifications]

Comment: What had you tried? Where is the problem?

Comment: There's no question for this. I was just curious

Comment: `text.substring(0, text.indexOf("dog", text.indexOf("dog")+1)+"dog".Length)` of course **it is not a production code** (you need to check if indexof doesn't return -1) ... this question is duplicate of bazillion question here - how to search text in text in C# - should be downvoted and closed as duplicate

Comment: @Selvin Wait...no, you are getting me wrong here. It's totally original

Comment: @Selvin And to search text in text I am not needed to ask a question because that can be done by Contains method...No Offence

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions (aka Regex), you could solve this in a straightforward way.

```
    var regex = new Regex("dog");
    var matches = regex.Matches(text);
    var secondIndex = matches[1].Index;
```

Watch out for word delimiters like spaces or punctuation marks. You can use [search engine of your choice] to lookup some Regex Cheat Sheet, since there is somewhat of an entry barrier to Regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *regular expresssions* and *Linq* for this:

When given `text` and `word` to find

```
  string text = 
    "This is some text about a dog. The word dog \nappears in this text a number of times. This is the end";

  string word = "dog";
```

We can find the `result` as

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  

  ...
  
  // we want 2nd match of the "dog" if it exists:
  var match = Regex
    .Matches(text, @$"\b{Regex.Escape(word)}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Skip(1) // skip the 1st match
    .FirstOrDefault(); // take the second

  string result = null == match
    ? text // we don't have 2nd "dog" word at all
    : text.Substring(0, match.Index + match.Length);

  // Let's have a look at result variable
  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
This is some text about a dog. The word dog
```